# Is this possible to change dropdown arrow up and down in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to change bootstrap dropdown arrow up and down while clicking the dropdown menu. Is this possible using css?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
li.open > a > span{
   border-top: 0px !important;
   border-bottom: 4px dashed !important;
}
```

It will select your span ( which is basically your arrow pointing up or down ) when the list is opened ie. when it contains class `.open` . Then it will change the spans css definition and turn the arrow.

**Output:**

```css
li.open > a > span {
  border-top: 0px !important;
  border-bottom: 4px dashed !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
   
      <span class="caret"></span>
     </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: This was flagged as low quality by community users even though it is the right answer. Please make sure you create a demo of your code or explain it to avoid flags and gain upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

Add below code bottom of you css style. and let me know if its works or not.

```
.dropdown.open .caret {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-bottom: 4px dashed;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

Example on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/cssmaster/details/QjgaYJ/)

Comment: Yes It works @Manish. but I'll suggest next time you should create a fiddle or a working example rather than asking OP to check your code. And Welcome to SO.